# Laravel: Executing PostgreSQL currval() function in Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql

How to execute PostgreSQL function currval() with Laravel ?

I tried this:

```
DB::select("SELECT currval('public.\"users_id_seq\"')");
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
>>> DB::select("SELECT currval('public.\"users_id_seq\"')");
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[55000]: Object not in prerequisite state: 7 ERROR:  currval of sequence "users_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session (SQL: SELECT currval('public."users_id_seq"'))'
```

Comment: I think that should work. Are you sure the error isn't something else?

Comment: @IGP I have updated the error message with more details. This other command works fine: `DB::select("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.users");`.

Comment: Have you tried actually running currval inside the postgres database?

Comment: @IGP yes and it works fine.

Comment: What about not using so either not using public or so many colons? `DB::select("SELECT currval('users_id_seq')");`

Comment: @IGP same error message with this syntax

Comment: According to something I found in the [postresql mail messages](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/dcc563d10804281922o130ab50j5681696114322e5a%40mail.gmail.com), maybe you should use `nextval` instead of `currval`.